# How to read form parameters with helidon-se

Tags: java, reactive, helidon, form-parameter

What is the right way to read form parameters in helidon-se.

I have tried doing the following without success.

1. Add **DefaultMediaSupport.formParamReader()** to the webserver:

```
WebServer.builder()
 .addReader(...) // added here
 .build()
```

Then reading the `request::content` with

```
request.content()
  .as(FormParams.class)
  .thenAccept(...) // never called
```

2. Read directly from the **Request::content**:

```
DefaultMediaSupport.formParamReader()
  .unmarshall(..., FormParams.class)
  .thenAccept(...) // never called
```

Both cases the client (browser/httpie) times out after `30s` and the request isn't handled.

So, what is the right way to read form parameters from a request body in helidon-se.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this example helps? https://github.com/oracle/helidon/tree/2.3.4/examples/media/multipart

Answer (score 3):

The reader for `FormParams` is available out-of-the-box, you don't have to explicitly register it (unless you've disabled the default readers). It only supports two content types:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `text/plain`

You can use it like this:

```
req.content().as(FormParams.class).thenAccept(fp -> {
    fp.first("foo")
      .ifPresentOrElse((greeting) -> res.send(greeting),
              () -> res.status(400).send());
});
```

You can test this with curl:

```
curl -X POST -d 'foo=bar' http://localhost:8080/abc
```

In HTML the form would look like this:

```
<form action="/abc" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" name="submit">
</form>
```

---

Helidon also has support for `multipart/form-data`:

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-media-multipart</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configure the media support in the `WebServer` builder:

```
WebServer.builder(createRouting())
         .addMediaSupport(MultiPartSupport.create())
```

Then use it like this:

```
req.content().as(ReadableMultiPart.class).thenAccept(multiPart -> {
    multiPart.field("foo")
             .ifPresentOrElse((part) -> res.send(part.as(String.class)),
                     () -> res.status(400).send());
});
```

You can test it with curl like this:

```
curl -X POST -F 'foo=bar' http://localhost:8080/abc
```

In HTML the form would look like this:

```
<form action="/abc" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" name="submit">
</form>
```